# Mediawiki plugin to add markdown support?

Tags: markdown, mediawiki

Is there a good, maintained mediawiki plugin that supports markdown? The mediawiki syntax is somewhat alien after you're spending your entire day writing Markdown.

Answer (score 1):

There are some [Existing Addons Markdown support](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Requests_for_comment/Markdown#Existing_Markdown_support), but all are "unmaintained".
I used [MarkdownExtraParser](https://www.mediawiki.org/w/index.php?oldid=3741907) and worked with some minor bugs.

Comment: Yeah, the issue is maintenance. What issues in particular did you have with MarkdownExtraParser?

Comment: I could not use Markdown definition lists. But 99% worked well.